# How to Change Input Button Font color?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code on a form button and I can't change the color of it's internal text:

```
<input type="button" name="continue" value="" class="next">

input.next {
color: white;
background: #199dd9;
text-align: left;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

The other styles (i.e. text-align, bg color) work, but the font color is still black. I inspect in devtools and nothing seems to be overwriting it.

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/wrqcccm5/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `<input>` tag, use HTML5's `<button>` tag.

```css
button.next {
color: white;
background: #199dd9;
text-align: left;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<button name="continue" class="next">Click me!</button>
```